# Returning values in Java

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble understanding pretty basic Java code, I can't figure out how in the end of compiling x=2. Because through my logic it should be 4. The code itself:

```
public class eksami_harjutused {

public static int x=2;
   public static int y=2;  

   public static void main(String[] args) {     
     foo(bar(foo(x)));      
     System.out.println("main x,y: "+x+" "+y);
   }  

   public static int foo(int x) {     
     x++;
     y++;   
     System.out.println("foo x,y: "+x+" "+y);
     return x;
   }

   public static int bar(int x) {
     int z=0, y=10, u=0;    
     --y;
     for(y=1; y<(x*x); y++) {
       for(z=1; z<x; z++) { 
         u++;
       }
     }
     System.out.println("bar x,y: "+x+" "+y);
     return z;       
   }           
}
```

It prints out:

foo x,y: 3 3

bar x,y: 3 9

foo x,y: 4 4

main x,y: 2 4

Comment: It would help others when you post the logs you printed.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger.  This way you will be able to see what each line of code does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `x` is passed by value - since it is `int` type, so any modification to `x` in the callee functions will not affect `x` in the caller function. You can think of giving a copy of value in `x` to the callee, and the callee can do whatever with it without affecting the `x` in the scope of the caller.

Passing by value is done for all the primitive types in Java. And passing by reference is done for the rest (Object - note that array is Object).

Another thing is the effect of variable shadowing in `foo` and `bar` methods: `x` is declared as parameter to `foo` and `bar`, so the class member `x` is shadowed. Any access to `x` in `foo` and `bar` methods will refer to the argument passed in, not the class member `x`.

The value of `x` printed in the `main` method is from the class member `x`, which is never touched during the execution of the program.

In contrast, you can see the variable `y` modified twice in 2 calls to the `foo` method, since `y` in `foo` method will refer to the class member `y`. The `y` in `bar` method, however, refer to the local variable `y` declared in the `bar` method.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanations, I didn't know about passing variables by value.

Answer (score 0):

Because int is passed by value, you would not expect x to be incremented in foo(). You can try org.apache.commons.lang.mutable.MutableInt since Integer class is also immutable.